# Missing schema errors when using an Xsd to validate Xml from a serialized WCF Proxy class

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xml-serialization

I'm trying to validate a serialized WCF Proxy class using an Xsd.

I've noticed that the generated Xml, isn't including the namespace on the parent element, but child elements have it. This means my validation throws **could not find schema information for the element** type errors.

If I manually add a default namespace, then the schema validation works.

My question is, if the request object has a serialization attribute for the namespace, why isn't that being generated automatically?

This is how I generate the serialized Xml for the proxy:

```
var path = @"C:\DataRequest.xml";
var data = new DataRequest(); 
using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(path))
{
   var serializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
   serializer.Serialize(fileWriter, data);
   fileWriter.Close();
}
```

This produces the following DataRequest.xml:

```
<DataRequest>
  <Data xmlns="urn:some:name:space">
    <Id>1</Id>
  </Data>
</DataRequest>
```

Here's my request object with the namespace serialization attribute:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.17929")]
<other attributes I snipped>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:some:name:space")]
public partial class DataRequest : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by dynamically getting the Namespace value when serializing.

Here's the modified function:

```
var dataType = data.GetType();
var xmlAttribute = (XmlTypeAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(dataType, typeof(XmlTypeAttribute));
XNamespace ns = xmlAttribute.Namespace;
using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
{
   var xSerializer = new XmlSerializer(dataType, ns.NamespaceName);
   xSerializer.Serialize(fileWriter, data);
   fileWriter.Close();    
}
```

The code came from this SO answer:
[How can I dynamically read a classes XmlTypeAttribute to get the Namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706725/how-can-i-dynamically-read-a-classes-xmltypeattribute-to-get-the-namespace)

Answer (score 1):

I found that when using the XmlSerializer, to get the namespace at the root, one needs to apply the [XmlRootAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to the target class.

Comment: My proxy class is auto generated though from a wsdl though?